# NPE found when trying to call built-in contact in RestComm

Tags: restcomm

When I tried to make a call with built-in number, it ran into an error as follows. I am new to restcomm and don't know what causes the error, anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

```
15:59:29,355 ERROR [org.restcomm.connect.telephony.Call] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7) java.lang.NullPointerException: org.restcomm.connect.commons.fsm.TransitionFailedException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.restcomm.connect.commons.fsm.FiniteStateMachine.transition(FiniteStateMachine.java:89) [restcomm-connect.commons-8.1.0.1143.jar:8.1.0.1143]
at org.restcomm.connect.telephony.Call.onReceive(Call.java:495) [restcomm-connect.telephony-8.1.0.1143.jar:8.1.0.1143]
at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:]
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:506) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.restcomm.connect.telephony.Call$Failed.execute(Call.java:1120) [restcomm-connect.telephony-8.1.0.1143.jar:8.1.0.1143]
at org.restcomm.connect.commons.fsm.FiniteStateMachine.transition(FiniteStateMachine.java:87) [restcomm-connect.commons-8.1.0.1143.jar:8.1.0.1143]
... 11 more

15:59:29,373 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.parser.NioPipelineParser] (pool-AffinityJAIN-thread-6) serving msg on call id 1486742368291
15:59:29,379 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (pool-AffinityJAIN-thread-6) <message
from="60.16.4.62:52022"
to="192.168.0.2:5063"
time="1486742369379"
isSender="false"
transactionId="z9hg4bk-3336-02f2354632b4a0cec69192570e702894"
callId="1486742368291"
firstLine="ACK sip:+1234@iwenda.me SIP/2.0"
>
<![CDATA[ACK sip:+1234@iwenda.me SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 1486742368291
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Alice Alissys" <sip:alice@iwenda.me>;tag=1486742368489
To: <sip:+1234@iwenda.me>;tag=79083205_0a919ed8_57a5b08a_badb824d
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS 60.16.4.62:52022;branch=z9hG4bK-3336-02f2354632b4a0cec69192570e702894;rport=52022;received=60.16.4.62
CSeq: 2 ACK
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>
```

the command I use is `docker run  -i -t --rm --name=restcomm-myInstance -v /var/log/restcomm/:/var/log/restcomm/ -e STATIC_ADDRESS="my eth0 ip" -e RESTCOMM_HOSTNAME="mydomain.name" -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/env_files/restcomm_env_locally.sh" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65000-65050:65000-65050/udp restcomm/restcomm:latest`

Comment: RestComm-Docker  container philosophy has changed, after RMS5 integration. Please pull latest tag again and run command like so:  "docker run  -i -t --rm --name=restcomm-myInstance -v /var/log/restcomm/:/var/log/restcomm/ -e RCBCONF_STATIC_ADDRESS="my eth0 ip" -e RCBCONF_RESTCOMM_HOSTNAME="mydomain.name" -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/env_files/restcomm_env_locally.sh" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5080:5080 -p 5081:5081 -p 5082:5082 -p 5083:5083 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65050:65000-65050/udp restcomm/restcomm:latest "

Comment: @LefterisBanos I did as you suggested, but it did not work, see https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/issues/1797 for updates